# how to assign the data result of ajax response of cgridview custom button's click event to a php variable in yii 1.x?

Tags: jquery, yii

I have a custom button in CGridView. There's a click event where by I have to pass the id of the row to the controller action in order to do a query.

```
             'options' => array(
                 'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                     'url' => "js:$(this).attr('href')",
                     'success' => 'function(data){
                            $("#detail").html(data);
                            $("#detail-dialog").dialog("open"); return false;
                        }',
                     'update' => '#detail'
                 )
             )
```

Once I get the result from the controller action, I open a dialog box. I want to have that data assigned to a PHP variable because I will need it in order to loop and create a CJuitabs inside the CJuiDialog. instead of doing `$("#detail").html(data);`

In the same file uner the CGridView, I have this CJuiDialog script that pops out.

```
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
        'id' => 'detail-dialog',
        'options' => array(
            'title' => 'Dialog Box Title' . $data->id,
            'autoOpen' => false,
            'modal' => true,
            'width' => 550,
            'height' => 450,
        ),
    )); ?>

<div id="#detail></div>
<?php
$this->endWidget();
?>
```

I want to put CJuitabs inside that CJuiDialog and I need to loop some data for producing the number of tabs dynamically.

How do I assign that ajax `data` to a php variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by generating the whole CJuiTabs from the controller and fed the view file that calls a javascript that fires the CJuiDialog box